# PHP TinyPHP size limit - strip whitespaces / obfuscation

Tags: php, obfuscation

there's a really neat little program called TinyPHP, all it does is take out all whitespace, take out all comments, and replace variable names with shorter ones. its not much of an obfuscator but that, and my file being wrapped up in a phar, is good enough for me.

only problem is there is a size limit on the input, and i cant figure out how to increase it. cant find the parameter in the code. could someone please help? 
its just 3 pages. its here:  https://github.com/mattgaidica/TinyPHP

thanks

[image: binary nul]

Comment: there is no restriction on the snippet size in php side, the full string is passed into `get_token_all`

Comment: yea sorry, just noticed; it didnt like the binary data, the NUL's,which stopped it. hmmmmm.

Comment: that should not be an issue, check your error log when its running you might need to adjust something in your `php.ini`

Comment: what are they officiall called; you know where the background is black and writing is white, saying NUL ?

Comment: please post an image i am not sure what your talking about

Comment: edited my question with image, screenshot from notepad++

Comment: do you have international chars ?

Comment: They are called [control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character).

Comment: thanks. the problem i've realised is also in copy and pasting them from notepad++. is there a way to get round this?